# User profile picture

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am Starting A Project with apostrophe-cms as CMS.
one thing which I need is the ability to add user profile pictures.
I have seen that it is feasible in the demo that they provide [here.](http://demo-cjgnd6id400y94ygz0upkrnv2.apostrophecms.org/blog/test)

I have searched the docs how to do this but haven't seen a direct hint to it.
Can someone point me in the right direction o how to achieve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add an `apostrophe-images` widget to the schema of the piece responsible for managing user profiles, `apostrophe-users` in this case.

In your `lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'thumbnail',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
      label: 'Profile Picture',
      options: {
        limit: 1,
        aspectRatio: [100, 100]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

You can change `limit` and `aspectRatio` to suite your needs or omit them altogether.

You can view the code for how the demo does what it does by reviewing the code

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-sandbox/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-sandbox/